# Derivative of: $f(x) = x^2e^{-x^2} $ for $|x| \le1$ and $ f(x) = \frac{1}{e} $ for $|x| > 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

I would like to get the derivative (one-sided if needed) of this function:
$$f(x) =\begin{cases}
 x^2e^{-x^2} & \text{for $|x|\le 1$} \\[6px]
\dfrac{1}{e} & \text{for $|x| > 1$}
\end{cases}
$$
What I got:

for $|x| < 1$
$$ f'(x) = 2xe^{-x^2}+x^2 e^{-x^2}2(-x)=2xe^{-x^2}(1-x^2) $$
for $x > 1$
$$ f'(x) = 0 $$
and for $x=1$ and $x=-1$ I am not sure. Here are my thoughts:
$$ f'(1+)=\lim_{{x} \to {1+}} \frac{\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{e}}{x-1} = 0 $$
and
$$ f'(1-)=\lim_{{x} \to {1-}}\frac{x^2e^{-x^2}-1^2e^{-1^2}}{x-1} = ? $$
here I am not sure. After this do the same for $-1$.

Does any of this make sense? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the function $f$ is even, therefore $f'(x)$ is odd. in particular $f'(\pm) 1) = 0 = f'(0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit
$$
f'(1{-})=\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}
$$
coincides with the derivative of $g(x)=x^2e^{-x^2}$ (defined on $\mathbb{R}$) at $1$, because this function is differentiable. Since
$$
g'(x)=2xe^{-x^2}-2x^3e^{-x^2}
$$
we have
$$
g'(1)=2e^{-1}-2e^{-1}=0
$$

Comment: So I have to show that the function is differentiable at $1$ and $-1$? I guess I would do this by showing that the limits from positive and negative direction are equal at points $1$ and $-1$ (4 limits)?

Comment: @Mykybo Yes, you need to do that. But you already showed the limit from the right at $1$ is $0$, so the function $f$ is differentiable at $1$. Finally, since $f(-x)=f(x)$, the same is true at $-1$.

Comment: isn't differentiability defined as limits from positive direction and negative direction being equal to each other? If that is so, then how is  the limit from the right at $1$ enough to show differentiability at $1$?

Comment: @Mykybo I didn't say that: you already had the limit from the right, I showed you how to compute the limit from the left.